# CSS3 custom checkbox just doesn't do anything

Tags: html, forms, css, checkbox

So I found a cool css3 checkbox example http://codepen.io/CreativeJuiz/pen/BiHzp

Now I'm trying to apply this to my HTML but just nothing is happening. This is the first time I've tried styling checkboxes  and I find it to be a real challenge.

Here is the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dJL8v/).

```
<div class="fb-checkbox">
      <label id="item21_0_label"><input id="item21_0_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" data-hint="" value="Conference" /><span id="item21_0_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Conference</span></label>
      <label id="item21_1_label"><input id="item21_1_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Incentive campaign" /><span id="item21_1_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Incentive campaign</span></label>
      <label id="item21_2_label"><input id="item21_2_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Incentive travel" /><span id="item21_2_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Incentive travel</span></label>
      <label id="item21_3_label"><input id="item21_3_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Awards dinner" /><span id="item21_3_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Awards dinner</span></label>
      <label id="item21_4_label"><input id="item21_4_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Product launch" /><span id="item21_4_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Product launch</span></label>
      <label id="item21_5_label"><input id="item21_5_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Hospitality" /><span id="item21_5_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Hospitality</span></label>
      <label id="item21_6_label"><input id="item21_6_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Comms and marketing" /><span id="item21_6_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Comms and marketing</span></label>
      <label id="item21_7_label"><input id="item21_7_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Reward &amp; Recoginition scheme" /><span id="item21_7_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Reward &amp; Recoginition scheme</span></label>
      <label id="item21_8_label"><input id="item21_8_checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="Project_type[]" type="checkbox" value="Design brief" /><span id="item21_8_span" class="fb-fieldlabel">Design brief</span></label>
    </div>
```

css:

```
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
position: relative!important;
padding-left: 25px!important;
cursor: pointer!important;
}


[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:before {
content: ''!important;
position: absolute!important;
left: 0!important top: 2px!important;
width: 17px!important; height: 17px!important;
border: 1px solid #aaa!important;
background: #f8f8f8!important;
border-radius: 3px!important;
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3)!important;
}


[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:after {
content: '✔'!important;
position: absolute!important;
bottom: 0!important; left: 4px!important;
font-size: 25px!important;
color: #09ad7e!important;
transition: all .5s!important;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label span:after {
opacity: 0!important;
transform: scale(0)!important;
}

[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span:after {
opacity: 1!important;
transform: scale(1)!important;
}

[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label span:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label span:before {
box-shadow: none!important;
border-color: #bbb!important;
background-color: #ddd!important;
}

[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label span:after {
color: #999!important;
}

[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label span {
  color: #aaa!important;
}

/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label span:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label span:before {
border: 1px dotted blue!important;
}
```

Using it on this site: http://www.jimharrison.co.uk/

I've also tried to follow tutorials to get this working and while it roughly makes sense I just can't manage to apply it to my markup! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `<input>`s **outside** the `<label>` elements.

You should have a `for=""` atribute in the `<label>` to relate for the input `#id`

**Working Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/verber/DwYNC/11/

Comment: NICE. All I needed was for someone to fill in the gap of my understanding of this and you have! SO appreciated, thank you. Just some minor tweaks now to get it positioned how I want :)

Answer (score 2):

A plus sign (“+”) is used to target an adjacent sibling of an element, essentially, something immediately following something.

In the html you've written, the inputs are children of the labels, so naturally, the css rules utilizing the "adjacent selector" will not apply.

Comment: Added in a + sign for the label and span but still not luck whatsoever. I've tried so many different ways of applying the CSS including other tutorials and then with those tried making sure my selectors were right but never had anything work. SO annoying!

Comment: Look at the html in the codepen example you linked again. The checkbox input comes _before_ the label. That's why `[type="checkbox"]:checked + label` works. That line of css basically reads like this: If there's a checkbox and it is checked, apply these styles to the first `<label>` that comes after it. And I don't mean "comes after it" as in "it displays after it", I mean "is literally written after it in the code".

Comment: Oh right I see - at first I couldn't figure out what I was missing as I thought what I was doing would just apply to all checkboxes and labels but it literally is like a puzzle - just make sure everything is in the right order.

Thanks, this is also educational!